# Combine unequal 2D numpy array to 3D array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

How two or more 2D numpy array can be combined by its rows.

I have two numpy arrays x and y.

x and y have different shape. Only number of rows = 14 are same in both the arrays:

```
x = np.ones(14).reshape(14,1)

array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])

y = np.zeros(42).reshape(14,3)

array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

I want to create 3D array from two or more 2D arrays.

The desired result is:

```
[[[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]
 [[1.], [0., 0., 0.]]]
```

Comment: That's not a 3d array.  It is 2d object dtype.  Why do you need to combine them?

Comment: You can't have a ragged array, but you can make a bigger 2D array

Comment: Please add a plain python tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use comprehension loop
and you can discard the `list()` if you are ok with output is list of arrays

```
import numpy as np

x = np.ones([14,1])
y = np.zeros([14,3])

arr1 = [[list(x[i]),list(y[i])] for i in range(14)]

arr1
[[[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]],
 [[1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]]
```